# How to make a GET request and place parameters in the header

Tags: php, html, http-headers, httprequest

I read on one of the [Google pages](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#RequestToken) for its OAuth mechanism that you can send a **OAuthGetRequestToken** request by using the:

> Authorization header of a GET or POST
>   request. Use "Authorization: OAuth".
>   All parameters listed above can go in
>   the header, except for scope and
>   xoauth_displayname, which must go
>   either in the body or in the URL as a
>   query parameter.

I've been looking around the web for quite awhile now as to what this means. Can anybody clear this up for me? And I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I use PHP as my scripting language so any information specific to php would be appreciated. More specifically:

-How do you send a header with additional information?
-How do you read back the header?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [OAuth extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php)?

Comment: Now that you bring it up, I had seen that and was unsure whether or not it would somehow interfere with cakephp -- which is what I'm using right now. Do you know if it would? And to answer your main question, I want to do it myself at least once & well I'm just curious about sending headers